# Why does nesting print(int(str)) in this for loop cause an error in Python 3?

Tags: python

Consider the following Python 3 code:

```
a = 5349234832
for i in range(6):
    print(int(str(a)[0:i]))
```

I get the error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10" when running this code. On the other hand, something like this works perfectly fine:

```
print(int(str(a)[0:5]))
```

(It returns 53492, as you'd expect.) I thought the error might be that the variable i is not an int, so I tried:

```
a = 5349234832
for i in range(6):
    print(int(str(a)[0:int(i)]))
```

This throws the same error though. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `i` will equal `0` on the first iteration of the for-loop.
- `str(a)[0:0]` returns the empty string (since there's nothing to slice).
- `int('')` raises your ValueError.

---

If you want to avoid `i` equaling `0`, start the range from 1:

```
a = 5349234832
for i in range(1, 6):
    print(int(str(a)[0:i]))
```